# Blender3D : Python script issue "ImportError: No module named MyModule"

Tags: python, blender

Hi I'm trying to use multiple python files in my Blender3D script.  (eg. MyScript.py and MyModule.py).  MyScript.py looks like:

```
import bpy
import math
from add_utils import AddObjectHelper, add_object_data
import mathutils

# this line doesn't work
import MyModule

#### REGISTER ####

def register():
    pass

def unregister():
    print("Finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Running the script within Blender3D, I get the error:

```
"ImportError: No module named MyModule"
```

I have setup Blender3D's "script" folder to point at the folder containing my script and MyModule.py.

Thanks for any help.

J

Comment: If you print `sys.path` before `import MyModule`, is the path to your module in that list?

Comment: hmm no it's not.  How would I go about telling Blender about this path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something has to add the proper path to the `sys.path` variable. I don't know it for Blender specifically, but in general, you could add it as follows:

```
sys.path.append(r'.\mymodule')            # Relative path
sys.path.append(r'C:\path\to\my\module')  # Absolute path
```

The one to use depends on the conditions you are running under: if your script is in some (for Blender) dedicated scripts folder, you could use the first one. If you run it from (for example) a `Program Files` folder, use the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that worked for me was running my python script with the following terminal command

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 path/to/script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cliche I use when I have external modules that live in the same directory with the .blend file is:

```
basedir =os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath) 
if basedir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(basedir)

import marchingCubes

# this next part forces a reload in case you edit the source after you first start the blender session
import imp
imp.reload(marchingCubes)
```

I derived it from http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_2/info_tips_and_tricks.html which actually has a bug in that it uses `os.path.basename` when you really need `os.path.dirname`.